# How to let pyttsx3 only listen when a command is given?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, pyttsx3

I would like pyttsx3 to only listen when a click some sort of button or speak some sort of hotword otherwise it should stay quiet and keep waiting for my command.

My code runs in a loop like shown below:

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":  # main program
    wish()
    while True:
        # if 1:

        query = takecommand().lower()

        # logic building for tasks

        if "open notepad" in query:
            npath = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"
            os.startfile(npath)

        elif 'hi' in query or 'hello' in query:
            speak('Hello sir, how may I help you?')
time.sleep(3)
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How About this:

```
Wake = "Hey Robot" #here you can use whatever word you want
while True: 

    text = get_audio().lower()# this takes the audio. Change this for the name of your audio function

    if text.count(Wake) > 0:
        speak("I am On.")
        text = get_audio().lower()#This make it say I am on when it is activated. And then start listening
    #Erase the .lower() if your talk function has it implemented
    hi_words = ["hello", "hi",]

    for phrase in hi_words:
        if phrase in text:
            speak("Hello sir, how may I help you")
```

This will make the program activate when you say the wake word. Then it will wait for a command, Afterwards it will go to sleep and wait till you say the wake word again